# Understand expired glibc signature key

Tags: glibc, signature, gnupg

This is the first time I try to correctly check the GPG signatures of the sources I use to build a cross compiler toolchain. With `glibc`, I found an interesting issue:

```
https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.39.tar.xz
https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.39.tar.xz.sig
```

Problem for me:

- Signature made 2024/01/31
- Key expired    2022/07/23

The sig file uses the following key:

```
pub  rsa4096/16792B4EA25340F8
     created: 2016-08-02  expired: 2022-07-23  usage: SC  
     trust: unknown       validity: expired
sub  rsa4096/4B54EAAC6E498A05
     created: 2016-08-02  expired: 2022-07-23  usage: E   
[ expired] (1). Carlos O'Donell <carlos@systemhalted.org>
[ expired] (2)  Carlos O'Donell (Work) <carlos@redhat.com>
[ expired] (3)  Carlos O'Donell (Work) <codonell@redhat.com>
```

and I cannot find one that is not expired. However, how can the fingerprint be valid,
and hence glibc been signed with an already expired key?

```
src gpg --verify glibc-2.39.tar.xz.sig                     
gpg: assuming signed data in 'glibc-2.39.tar.xz'
gpg: Signature made Wed 31 Jan 2024 11:05:38 PM CET
gpg:                using RSA key 7273542B39962DF7B299931416792B4EA25340F8
gpg: Good signature from "Carlos O'Donell <carlos@systemhalted.org>" [expired]
gpg:                 aka "Carlos O'Donell (Work) <carlos@redhat.com>" [expired]
gpg:                 aka "Carlos O'Donell (Work) <codonell@redhat.com>" [expired]
gpg: Note: This key has expired!
Primary key fingerprint: 7273 542B 3996 2DF7 B299  9314 1679 2B4E A253 40F8
```

There must be something I am missing!